# How to call slack webhooks api in chrome extension(crx)?

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome-extension, webhooks, slack

I am trying to send a message to Slack via web hooks API in Chrome Extension.

I made extension with `reactjs` and call this with `fetch` function.
However when I send message, I can see this error message in console.

```
The SSL certificate used to load resources from https://hooks.slack.com will be distrusted in M70
```

And basically it has cross-domain issue, I guess.

Here is part of my code

```
var payload = {
    text : '@juneyoung ' + confirmMessage 
}
var data = new FormData();
data.append('json', JSON.stringify(payload));

let fetchOptions = {
    method : 'POST',
    headers : {
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
    },
    body : data
}

fetch(ref.sharedValue.slackAPIUrl, fetchOptions)
    .then(resp => {
        console.log('resp :: ', resp);
        resp.json()
    })
    .then(json => {
        console.log('API Result ', json);
        ref.showNotice('success', 'Success!', true);
    });
```

`ref` is just a variable which contains React Component(`this` in class file).

Is there anyway to send Slack web hooks request in Chrome Extension?

Comment: The message says `hooks.slack.com` has a problem with its certificate, it's not related to your code.

Comment: @wOxxOm However I can send message with same request with `curl`. It only matters call in a browser. So I wonder is there any other way to make it success(for instance, add some extra parameters ...)

Comment: You can disregard the message, it doesn't prevent the connection.

Comment: @wOxxOm Indeed. It is just ignorable warning. The problem solved with adjust payload. I will post the answer soon. Thanks